# how to call a function in an if stament JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

ok I have an overlay with a button "fruit" and "Veggie".
let's say I click fruit - 12 fruit buttons will pop up. a back button will pop on top. if I click the back button, I want to return to previous page that has the "fruit" and "veggie" button.

My problem: I wrote 2 scripts, one for "fruit" button and "veggie" button and one for the back button, but returning either from the fruit or veggie page.

I wanted to make an `if else` statement so when for ex, I click fruits and I want to go back to main page, I can just call one of the back functions from the second script

I feel like there is a simple way of doing this but I just cant figure it out? can anyone hint at this please?

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#frbtn").click(function(){
                $("#vegbtn").hide();
                $(".fruit").show();

            });

            $("#vegbtn").click(function(){
                $("#frbtn").hide();
                $(".veggie").show();
            });


        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#backbtn").click(function backFruit(){
                $(".fruit").hide();
                $("#vegbtn").show();
                $("#frbtn").show();
            });

            $("#backbtn").click(function backVeg(){
                $(".veggie").hide();
                $("#vegbtn").show();
                $("#frbtn").show();
            });
        });
    </script>

<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
<!-- Button to close the overlay navigation -->
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

<!--back button-->
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="backbtn" >&#8678;</a>
<!-- Overlay content -->

<!--Fruits-->  
    <div class="overlay-content"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <button id="frbtn" class="overlay-icon dropbtn" >Fruits</button>
                    <div class="row">  
                        <div class="col-xs-3 fruit">
                            <button class="dropbtn overlay-icon">Apple</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 fruit">
                           <button class="dropbtn overlay-icon">Banana</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 fruit">
                             <button class="dropbtn overlay-icon">Orange</button>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                <br />
                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3 fruit">
                                <button class="dropbtn overlay-icon">Pear</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3 fruit">
                               <button class="dropbtn overlay-icon">Melon</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3 fruit">
                                 <button class="dropbtn overlay-icon">Plum</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                <br />
                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3 fruit">
                                <button class="dropbtn overlay-icon">Cherry</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3 fruit">
                               <button class="dropbtn overlay-icon">Water&#13;&#10;melon</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3 fruit">
                                 <button class="dropbtn overlay-icon">Peach</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                <br />
                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3 fruit">
                                <button class="dropbtn overlay-icon">Straw&#13;&#10;berry</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3 fruit">
                               <button class="dropbtn overlay-icon">Grape</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3 fruit">
                                 <button class="dropbtn overlay-icon">Ras&#13;&#10;berry</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <button id="vegbtn" class="dropbtn overlay-icon">Veggies</button>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 veggie">
                            <button class="dropbtn overlay-icon">Carrot</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 veggie">
                           <button class="dropbtn overlay-icon">Potato</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 veggie">
                             <button class="dropbtn overlay-icon">Tomato</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show your html code too

Comment: try my answer @Rgoat

Answer (score 1):

`Id` should be unique .so use `class for both back` button

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".backbtn").click(function back(){

               $(".fruit").hide();
               $(".veggie").hide();
               $("#vegbtn").show();
               $("#frbtn").show();
        });
    });
```

Comment: thanks works great! i guess if-else would be redundant in this case

Comment: if else not need because your going to show both div so it's not need here @Rgoat . if my answer is useful mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference

Answer (score 0):

Just hide both `div` and show both `buttons`.

```
 $(document).on("click", "#backbtn", function () {
            $(".fruit,.veggie").hide();
            $("#vegbtn,#frbtn").show();
        });
```